# Log4j2 createOnDemand="true" does not allow creation of new file on a daily basis

Tags: java, log4j2, java.util.logging

`Log4j2 createOnDemand="true"` does not allow creation of new file on a daily basis in-spite of using `RollingFile Appenders` with `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`.

Below is my `log4j2.xml` file.

I have two `appenders`, one is for all logs, another is for a custom purpose, which needs to be generated only on demand, but the `createOnDemand` is overriding the Rolling nature of the log and it is not allowing to create new log file for the custom log.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="App" 
                fileName="app.log" 
                filePattern="app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz} %-5p %l - %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="custom"
                 fileName="appCustom.log"
                 filePattern="appCustom.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log"
                 createOnDemand="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS zzz} %-5p %l - %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
        </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="AppLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
                <AppenderRef ref="App"/>
            </Logger>
        <Logger name="customLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="custom"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
                <AppenderRef ref="file" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the fix for the above issue.
This was an existing bug in lo4j2 which is fixed in the version - [2.13.1](https://blogs.apache.org/logging/entry/log4j-2-13-1-released)

Below are the links :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2759

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changes-report.html#a2.13.3

I was using 2.11.0

Upgrading resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The file is also not created if `fileName` contains one or more directories and one of them does not exists, e.g. `<RollingFile fileName="logs/appCustom.log"/>` fails if `logs` does not exist.

The directories are never created you need to take care of that yourself. Make sure you pay attention to the working directory where the directory is expected*. For example, it changes for every subproject of a Gradle project with multiple includes. Therefore you need `logs` in every included project.

Make sure to exclude the `logs` from git.

---

*  I guess it's the current working directory. Nothing mentioned at the crucial points and I cannot check the complete [40 pages docs of appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html).